# How can i get image by click button on GUI into another .py file in the same directory folder

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

`main.py`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import cv2
import os
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        self.loadimg.clicked.connect(self.load_img)

    def load_img(self):
        load_img_1, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image",
                                                                    options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        img = cv2.imread(load_img_1)

        if img is None:
            self.imglabel.setText("Cannot load the input image.")
        else:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img_ = QImage(img.data, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.imglabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img_))
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(img_)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imglabel.width(), self.imglabel.height())
        if load_img_1:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(load_img_1)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imglabel.width(), self.imglabel.height(),QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.imglabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.imglabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.imglabel.setScaledContents(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`classify.py`:

```
image = cv2.imread("/")
```

I am a beginner with python and machine learning. I have some problem with my learning.
I make a GUI in `main.py` and when I load an image by click button on gui `def load_img(self):`, I want the path of image link to `image = cv2.imread("/")` in `classify.py`, but I don't know how to do that. Futhermore, I want to how to show classify result on text label in the GUI and I don't know how, too.
So, I need to help from you and show me how I can do that.
Thank you so much.

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code and error message

Comment: how do you run second script ? (1) manually in console, (2) using `os.system()` or similar in first script (3) importing in first script and running function from second script ?

Comment: firstly, thanks for your editing correctly format of my post.

Comment: i want to run second script code by click a button on the gui, after i add image by click another button on gui into  image = cv2.imread("/") of second script code.
please show me how to do that. thanks you

Comment: in first script you can run second script using `os.system("python classify.py your_path")` and it will get path in `sys.argv` so second script  will need `cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: if `clasify.py` has code in function(s) - ie. `def somefunction(path): imread(path) `then you can `import clasify` and run function `clasify.somefunction(your_path)` and it will run `imread(your_path)`

Comment: thank you.
but i am a python beginner, so i don't clearly understand about your suggest. 
so, can you give me some examples.
thanks

Comment: first method with `os.system`: in `load_img` you use `os.system("python  clasify.py {}".format(load_img_1))` and it will run script with path as parameter. In `clasify.py` you have `import os` and then you can use `cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])` to get this path and read image.

Comment: second method: you use `import` to load modules `os`, `cv2`, `PyQt`. The same way you can use `import clasify` to load script and use it in `main.py` But in `clasify.py` code has to be in function - ie `def run(path):` so you can execute `clasify.run(load_img_1)`. Inside `run(path)` you have to use variable `path` in `cv2.imread(path)` and it will use `load_img_1`

Comment: thank you so much.
So, if i put image from "Load" button on GUI in main.py and link it to cv2.imread() of classify.py. And then, i click "Check" button on GUI in main.py to run classify.py and show the image result  on the label. i tried some methods but didn't work. 
i am feeling disappointed :(, can you help me.
thanks.

Comment: if you want image from `clasify` back to `main.py` then you have to use `import clasify` - and they you can do `output_image = clasify.some_function(load_img_1)` and then you can get `output_image` and display in GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `classify.py` put code in function with parameter ie. `path and then you can`import`it and run function with your image filename as parametr. If function will return image then`main` can get it and display.

classify.py

```
def run(path)

    image = cv2.imread(path)

    # ... machine learning code ...

    return image
```

main.py - see `import` and `image = clasify.run(filename)`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import cv2
import os

import classify # filename without .py

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        self.loadimg.clicked.connect(self.load_img)

    def load_img(self):
        load_img_1, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image",
                                                                    options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

        #img = cv2.imread(load_img_1)
        img = classify.run(load_img_1) # use it


        if img is None:
            self.imglabel.setText("Cannot load the input image.")
        else:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img_ = QImage(img.data, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.imglabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img_))
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(img_)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imglabel.width(), self.imglabel.height())
        if load_img_1:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(load_img_1)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imglabel.width(), self.imglabel.height(),QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.imglabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.imglabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.imglabel.setScaledContents(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please answer my comment below.

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page. You will have more place for code and error message. Stackoverflow is not forum and there is place only for one question (and many answers/solutions)